# Using child_process.exec to send a command returning 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-status-code-404, child-process

I have a simple server setup using NodeJs, from which I would like to send a command to the terminal on the server.

I'm trying to use child_process.exec to send a command, which when I run from the terminal works correctly.

The issue I'm having is that the POST method /unLock is not found. as a response i get.

```
POST /unLock 404 1.770 ms - 1186
```

I've included the code for the server and routes/views I have set up below, I'm new to node and trying to learn so any help would be appreciated.

## app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var exec = require('child_process').execSync;

var util = require('util')
//var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var app = express();

app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
})); 
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.get('/javascript/jquery.min.js', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile( __dirname + "/javascript" + "/jquery.min.js" );

});

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(200);

  });

//trying to send command here
//recieiving 404
app.post('/unLock', function (req, res) {
exec("ls -la", {stdio:[0,1,2]});
res.send(200);

console.log("button clicked");
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


module.exports = app;
```

## index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Home'
  });
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login', {
    title: 'login'
  });
});

router.get('/unLock', function(req, res){
    console.log("hello"); //this doesnt work 
});

router.get('/contact', function(req, res){
  res.render('contact', {
    title: 'Contact'
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

## index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function unLock() { 
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
                url: '/unLock',
    data: '',
    success: function (data) {
                }
       });
}
//call button.js
</script>

  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to SecureLock - beta 1.0</p>
    <form><input type='button' value='unLock' onclick='unLock()'/></form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `unLock()` JS function you do an AJAX call with the method `POST`, but in your route you have

```
router.get('/unLock', function(req, res){
    ...
});
```

so there is no route to respond to a `POST`. Change the line above to `router.post` *or* change the AJAX method to type `GET`. Probably the latter if you aren't actually sending any data to the server with the AJAX call.